# Install gcc 4.9 at ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gcc

Is there any way to install gcc 4.9 at ubuntu 18.04? I tried

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9 g++-4.9
```

but I get:

```
Package g++-4.9 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

I need this version for running some simulations with sniper.
Is there anyway to do it or I have to make a VM with ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Available is: `sudo apt install g++-4.8`

And the **no PIE** `gcc54-c++_5.4.0-ubuntu16_amd64.deb` https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ptHLaZXImpeMzq4xuuGGn5VjrvxNSop3/view?usp=sharing , **Ref.** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50213089/linking-error-with-gcc-g-7-3-0-on-ubuntu-18-04/50232797#50232797 → My answer.

Or add `xenial` to `/etc/apt/sources.list` temporarily : `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main
deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
```

... and do `sudo apt update && sudo apt install g++-4.9`

Comment: You are the best thanks a lot
A thought that if 4.9 was not available the same would happen with 4.8.

Comment: You can always use `$ apt-cache search g++ g++-4.8` ... and also use the on-line "Search & overview" page https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=g%2B%2B&searchon=names

Comment: Can I find/download gnat-4.x on ubuntu 18.04 somewhere?

Comment: I guess you can use e.g. the 14.04 `gnat-4.6` https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/gnat-4.6 ... or the 16.04 `gnat-4.9` https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/gnat-4.9 ... if the dependencies can fit 18.04 . ... Ref. https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gnat&searchon=names

Comment: Do not post links to random binaries on random cloud!

Answer (score 0):

in the server mode the default install don't add the universe repository in the sourcelist and only gcc8 and gcc7 is avaible in main.
Add the universe repository, update the repo and install gcc4.8