# Ubuntu 20.04 - gcc version lower than gcc-7

Tags: 20.04, gcc

I recently upgraded my Ubuntu version to the latest 20.04 release. Some of my earlier projects (developed on 16.04) were compiling just fine with a gcc version of 5 (gcc-5.4.0).

The default version in Ubuntu 20.04 is gcc-9. I'm trying to switch my gcc version down to 5. I've gone through several posts such as [How can I build and install gcc-5.4.0 on Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109933/how-can-i-build-and-install-gcc-5-4-0-on-ubuntu-18-04) and [How to choose the default gcc and g++ version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26498/how-to-choose-the-default-gcc-and-g-version), but the fact is that gcc-5 packages aren't even available for 20.04 (see https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gcc-5).

As expected, the command

```
sudo apt install gcc-5
```

does not work. Is there a way I can install gcc-5 (and gcc-4) on the latest release of Ubuntu 20.04? It seems like I will somehow have to install packages that are available only in earlier releases such as 16.04 or 18.04.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use an older version of GCC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229774/how-to-use-an-older-version-of-gcc)

Comment: GCC 5 is in xenial's repository, You can use 16.04's repository temporarily to install gcc-5.

Comment: I tried using the command - echo "deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial.list , but I receive the error - "The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file."

Comment: Can you help me figure out the right command for adding the xenial repo?

Comment: Xenial is still supported. Replace old-releases with archive

Comment: Okay perfect, I was able to install gcc-5. Thanks!

Comment: You can write your own solution and accept it (maybe after a few days) and this will then be marked as solved, and you gain some rep.

Comment: In case some runs into this looking for newer versions.  I wanted gcc-11 but Ubuntu came with gcc-9 https://tuxamito.com/wiki/index.php/Installing_newer_GCC_versions_in_Ubuntu

Answer (score 17):

As mentioned in the comment section, GCC versions lower than 7 are still available in xenial repository. You can follow the following steps to install gcc-5:

1. Add `xenial` to `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Open sources.list with sudo

> sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list

Add the following lines in the sources.list file

> deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main
> deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe

2. `sudo apt update`
3. `sudo apt install g++-5 gcc-5`

Reference answer: [Install gcc 4.9 at ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036108/install-gcc-4-9-at-ubuntu-18-04)

To change default gcc version to gcc 5 you can follow this [link](https://www.fosslinux.com/39386/how-to-install-multiple-versions-of-gcc-and-g-on-ubuntu-20-04.htm). Below I am adding the steps for completeness.

> sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-5 5
> sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-5 5

And then select the correct version manually as below:

> sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
> sudo update-alternatives --config g++

If you find this answer helpful, please also consider upvoting the reference answer from which most of my answer is borrowed.

Comment: I'd like to try his solution. What I do *not* want is to use a different default gcc/g++. Is this the case after install gcc-5 and g++-5?

Comment: In that case, you could just skip `update-alternatives` command. Just installing new gcc/g++ won't change the default.

Answer (score 1):

The **only** solution that worked for me is:

### Manual installing of .deb packages

*(sad programmer noises)*

1. Go to http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/
2. Download all .deb packages for gcc compiler version you want, f.e.:

> ```
> gpc-2.1-3.4_3.4.6-6ubuntu5_amd64.deb
> cpp-3.4_3.4.6-6ubuntu5_amd64.deb       lib32g2c0_3.4.6-6ubuntu5_amd64.deb
> g++-3.4_3.4.6-6ubuntu5_amd64.deb       libg2c0_3.4.6-6ubuntu5_amd64.deb
> g77-3.4_3.4.6-6ubuntu5_amd64.deb       libg2c0-dev_3.4.6-6ubuntu5_amd64.deb
> gcc-3.4_3.4.6-6ubuntu5_amd64.deb       libstdc++6-dbg_3.4.6-6ubuntu5_amd64.deb
> gcc-3.4-base_3.4.6-6ubuntu5_amd64.deb  libstdc++6-dev_3.4.6-6ubuntu5_amd64.deb
> ```

3. Manually install them by running command, f.e.:

> ```
> sudo dpkg -i ./gcc-3.4-base_3.4.6-6ubuntu5_amd64.deb 
> sudo dpkg -i ./cpp-3.4_3.4.6-6ubuntu5_amd64.deb
> sudo dpkg -i ./gcc-3.4_3.4.6-6ubuntu5_amd64.deb
> ```
>
> and so on...

Check the console output errors about package dependencies to figure out the package install order.

- *If you encounter error (bug probably) about crossdependency of "g++..." package to "libstdc++..." package and v.v. then run install command to update libstdc++ package with exact version number, f.e.:*

> ```
> sudo apt-get install libstdc++6
> ```

4. **Hooray!** Use installed gcc (g++) version by, f.e.:

> ```
> g++-3.4 -v
> ```

P.S.: of you're getting missing libs errors try

> ```
> export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:$LIBRARY_PATH
> ```

before the build

Comment: In my case I had to install differents lib (maybe not all was needed) : `cpp-4.9_4.9.4-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb       libcloog-isl4_0.18.4-2_amd64.deb         libisl15_0.18-4_amd64.deb      libmpfr4-dbg_3.1.4-1_amd64.deb
g++-4.9_4.9.4-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb       libcloog-isl-dev_0.18.4-2_amd64.deb      libisl-dev_0.22.1-1_amd64.deb  libstdc++-4.9-dev_4.9.4-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
gcc-4.9-base_4.9.4-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb  libgcc-4.9-dev_4.9.4-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb  libmpfr4_3.1.4-1_amd64.deb`