# How to set enviroment to use older gcc g++ version without changing default?

Tags: 20.04, gcc, csh

When trying to launch application I get this error:

```
/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1)
```

now this is certainly because I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS which has more recent versions of gcc than the software requires.

In the software's install directory the correct gcc is provided:

```
/software/lib/linux_gcc44x_64
```

So I thought in the cshrc may be I could point to it using:

```
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH "$SOFTWAREHOME/lib/linux_gcc44x_64"
```

but this does not work.

My default gcc is

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) 9.4.0
```

I do not want to mess with this but I would like somehow for the cshrc file to make the software use the correct older version.

A tutorial on how install old versions is [here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-switch-between-multiple-gcc-and-g-compiler-versions-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-focal-fossa) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235819/ubuntu-20-04-gcc-version-lower-than-gcc-7)

When I try to install from [old-releases.ubuntu](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gcc-4.4/) I get

```
dpkg: error processing package gcc-4.4 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured 
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gcc-4.4
```

Not sure what to do.

Addition of `ldd` output:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff1f7e9000)
libvsacpp.so => not found
libvpsl.so => not found
libgfortran.so.3 => not found
libvirtuos_sh.so => not found
libfastt_sh.so => not found
libcls_sh.so => not found
libcdsCommon_sh.so => not found
liboaDesign.so => not found
liboaDM.so => not found
liboaCM.so => not found
liboaTech.so => not found
liboaPlugIn.so => not found
liboaBase.so => not found
liboaCommon.so => not found
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ff77734d000)
libshdb_verilog.so => not found
libihdlGrUtils_sh.so => not found
libihdl_nc_sh.so => not found
libihdl_db_sh.so => not found
libihdl_schgen_sh.so => not found
libvisadev.so => not found
libtiParseSpice.so => not found
libshdb_spice.so => not found
libshdb_cdl.so => not found
libtiParseCdl.so => not found
libti5xBase.so => not found
libshdb_format.so => not found
libshdb_core.so => not found
libddpiServices_sh.so => not found
libddpi_sh.so => not found
libddbase_sh.so => not found
libil_sh.so => not found
libnmpil_sh.so => not found
libgdm_sh.so => not found
libgdmil_sh.so => not found
libccp_sh.so => not found
libpcdb_sh.so => not found
libckp_sh.so => not found
libdataReg_sh.so => not found
libddAccess_sh.so => not found
libdsCat_sh.so => not found
libnmp_sh.so => not found
libcla_sh.so => not found
libcdsIlIpc_sh.so => not found
libmpsc_sh.so => not found
libsman_sh.so => not found
libmpss_sh.so => not found
libmpi_sh.so => not found
liblbss_sh.so => not found
libem_sh.so => not found
liblbsc_sh.so => not found
libems_sh.so => not found
libemscpp_sh.so => not found
libxcf_sh.so => not found
lib_cadencehelp.so.2 => not found
libQtCore.so.4 => not found
libQtGui.so.4 => not found
libQt3Support.so.4 => not found
libQtXml.so.4 => not found
libQtSql.so.4 => not found
libQtNetwork.so.4 => not found
libXrender.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007ff777133000)
libXext.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007ff77711c000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007ff777111000)
libQtTest.so.4 => not found
libhedElaborator_sh.so => not found
libhdb_sh.so => not found
libhed_sh.so => not found
libvivatokens.so => not found
libviva_ade.so => not found
libvivadf2.so => not found
libviva.so => not found
libedser_sh.so => not found
libclalite_sh.so => not found
libhdbcla_sh.so => not found
libpcdbclaNoOA_sh.so => not found
libdrl.so => not found
libadt.so => not found
libsrrwriter.so => not found
libsrr.so => not found
libnxdb.so => not found
libpslNX.so => not found
libcdsenvutil.so => not found
libcdsenvxml.so => not found
liboccprop_sh.so => not found
liboccprophdb_sh.so => not found
libCdsXmotif.so.2 => not found
libXt.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6 (0x00007ff776ea0000)
libX11.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007ff776d63000)
libQtOpenGL.so.4 => not found
libQtSvg.so.4 => not found
libxerces-c.so.27 => not found
libxalan-c.so.110 => not found
libxalanMsg.so.110 => not found
libGL.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00007ff776cd9000)
libGLU.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1 (0x00007ff776c67000)
libcdsChms_sh.so => not found
libpapi_verilog.so => not found
libpapi_core.so => not found
libpapi_spice.so => not found
libpapi_cdl.so => not found
libasa.so => not found
libapa.so => not found
libte.so => not found
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ff776c5d000)
libnsl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007ff776c40000)
libelf.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libelf.so.1 (0x00007ff776c24000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007ff776a42000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff7768f1000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007ff7768d6000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff7766e4000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff777398000)
libSM.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6 (0x00007ff7766d9000)
libICE.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6 (0x00007ff7766bb000)
libxcb.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007ff776691000)
libGLdispatch.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x00007ff7765d7000)
libGLX.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007ff7765a3000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007ff776587000)
libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007ff77657e000)
libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007ff776564000)
libXau.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007ff77655c000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007ff776554000)
```

Comment: How exactly did you determine that the problem is related to the system's gcc version?

Comment: well other softwares not even related produce a similar problem when I did a web search; the solution being to use the correct gcc version. So I thought gcc would be a good place to start.

Comment: IMHO a better place to start would be to run `ldd` on the software's binary executable file to see exactly which libraries it is linking to - gcc/g++ shouldn't even be involved at runtime

Comment: thank you for the ldd suggestion libstdc++.so.6 is shown in there too.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the **full** output from `ldd`

Comment: @steeldriver updated.